# When encoding a JSON string, why does a leading 0 appear?

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP single dimension array, when using the `json_encode` function on that array I get a json object returned but it has a leading 0 before the opening curly brace `{`.

```
0{"a1000":"b1000","a1200":"b1200"}
```

The PHP array is:

```
Array
(
    [a1000] => b1000
    [a1200] => b1200
)
```

On the same page, with a different (but same structured) request, the json object that is returned does not have a leading 0.

The error in the Chrome console is:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Has anyone ever come across this problem before?

Comment: How are you generating the array? Are there any other outputs beforehand?

Comment: Are you sure you're not outputting a 0 somewhere? For associate arrays, json would return {0:{...}} so it seems you have a stray 0 somewhere. Open the file that gives you the json in your browser and you can check easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PHP is likely outputting the `0` before the JSON.  Although you didn't show all you code, you should double check all of the following:

- check there's no text before your `<?php` tag
- look for any rogue `echo` or `print` statements
- check that you're not using outputting functions such as `readfile()` or `var_dump()`